# Adding extra geom_point with differect scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add another set of points on top of a `geom_point`. The problem is that the initial dataset has a factor with 3 levels while the second doesn't. I want the first set of points to have different colors and shapes according to the factor levels and the second to be uniform. The plot is like this:

```
plot = ggplot() +
  geom_point(data1, 
              aes(x = x1, y = y1, 
              color = factor, shape = factor)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = factor_color) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = factor_shape)
```

When I add the other set of points,

```
plot +
geom_point(data2, 
           aes(x = x2, y = y2))
```

I get this error

> Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 3
> provided.

I understand why this happens.
But when I set the scales inside the second `geom_point`, `color = "red"` and `shape = 1` I get this error

> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

Is there a solution to this problem?

EDIT

Example data have this structure

```
data1 = data.frame(factor = factor(rep(letters[1:3], 3)),
                   x1 = rnorm(9),
                   y1 = rnorm(9))

data2 = data.frame(x2 = rnorm(6),
                   y2 = rnorm(6))

factor_color = scales::hue_pal()(3)
factor_shape = c(19, 15, 17)
```

Comment: Hi Katerina, when you post a question you should always provide a reproducible example. In this case your data are missing. You should provide a mock or something like that. Look for "reproducible examples"

Comment: I was adding the scales inside the aesthetics in the second `geom_point`. It worked when I took the out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In my example, I have no error.

Just guessed you data:

```
data1 <- data.frame(factor = factor(letters[1:4]),
                    x1 = rnorm(4),
                    y1 = rnorm(4))
data2 <- data.frame(factor = factor(letters[1:3]),
                    x2 = rnorm(3),
                    y2 = rnorm(3))

factor_color <- scales::hue_pal()(4)
factor_shape <- 1:4
```

Your code with two small changes.
I specified `data =` in both `geom_point`

```
library(ggplot2)

plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = data1, 
             aes(x = x1, y = y1, 
                 color = factor, shape = factor)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = factor_color) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = factor_shape)


plot +
  geom_point(data = data2, 
             aes(x = x2, y = y2))
```